# disconnected sql server when run stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to create or alter stored procedures, it automatically disconnects dbserver.

It only does so for stored procedure create,alter.

This is the error I get:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout
>   period has expired.)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Karthikeyan - Remote server or local server? Also, you started your post saying "when run sproc.." Then you ended up saying "create or alter sproc...". Which one is causing the disconnect? Is it just one particular sproc or is it for any sproc? More details will help

Comment: Check this out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325487

Comment: You need to give a lot more information: is the server local or remote; how are you running the script (SSMS, sqlcmd.exe or something else); is this consistently reproducible; are you absolutely sure that only `CREATE PROC` and `ALTER PROC` commands cause this problem; can you post a complete script that causes this error etc.

Comment: Server only not working . Local server is working. ALL stored Procedure create and alter automatically disconnected server connection in sqlserver.then after one more time connect username,pwd use to connect.

Comment: Other system same same sp working ,only my system not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's the problem but check the query execution option from Tools -> Options menu and go to Query Execution - > Sql Server -> Advanced section. As shown below Disconnect after the query executes option should be unchecked.
[image]